# control string in TRichEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Using two buttons  to add lines to a `TRichEdit` control; is there a way I can use the second button to continue the line of the first button?

I have tried using the control string sequence of #8 to backspace it, but that doesn't work for me. What else can I do?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do so by simply concatenating (adding) the second half of the string to the first half you've already added.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RichEdit1.Lines.Add('This is the first half');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LastLine: Integer;
begin
  LastLine := RichEdit1.Lines.Count - 1;
  // Make sure we've added some text before
  if LastLine <> -1 then
    RichEdit1.Lines[LastLine] := RichEdit1.Lines[LastLine] + 
        ', and here is the second half.';
end;
```